# FuelPHP, PDO and PostgreSQL - does they work together?

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, postgresql-9.1, fuelphp

I have to rewrite PHP project, and as a person who comes from CI and Kohana frameworks I'am looking into using FuelPHP - times changes, time to try something new. Only this project requires PostgreSQL.

I'am very new to FuelPHP, so my problem explanation can be foolish :). I've installed pgsql PDO module, set database, etc., so everything what PHP and PostgreSQL itself requires for work is set.

Now I want to know, is it possible, to get FuelPHP work with PostgreSQL? As I understand in current 1.3v only way is PDO, but for me somehow it doesn't work - no connection or select errors, just empty selects. I red somewhere that in 2.0v pgsql will be supported better, bet I don't think it's solution to use 2.0v beta release. :)

Currently I'am trying to understand if it will be possible to use FuelPHP for this project, because it's a long term work - ~6 months for rewrite for one person - but after that there will be included more programmers.

Comment: Using unfamiliar framework for critical project is worst thing that anyone can do. And, if you are doing this to an existing codebase, it will actually be harmful. **Slapping on a framework does no make the project better**.

Comment: I don't have a choice. CI doesn't fit for this project, Kohana is supported less and less, Symfony 2 is to big to pick it up, so I'am looking to something what is similar to CI and Kohana and fits this project, and the existing base is only db - everything else will be new. Of course we can always say, this is to hard, let's find easier way, but that's not the always best way - and as I said, picking up FuelPHP isn't as picking up Symfony, so for project itself it's not as critical as you may think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not perfect but FuelPHP works PostgreSQL. At least you can CRUD.

See http://docs.fuelphp.com/classes/database/introduction.html

There is a example configuration for PostgreSQL

// a PDO driver configuration, using PostgreSQL

Comment: Oh, thanks, now CRUD works for me as well. But do you have information, how limited PDO is? I mean, any "hard core" stuff like indexing, creating tables, adding columns, etc., will be made from proper tools. The web page itself will do CRUD but with complex selects.